# How can I check if user input already exists in an array in C?

Tags: c

I trying to check if user input already exists in an array. The code I have come up with so far seems to be working with one exception. When I start the program and enter 1s at the beginning, it only detects a repeat occurrence after I enter it a third time. With every other number this is not the case and I currently trying to wrap my head around why that is?

```
int main()
{
    int input;
    int num[16];

    printf("Enter the numbers from 1 to 16 in any order:\n");

        for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
            scanf("%d", &input);

            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                if(num[j] == input){
                    printf("You have already entered this number!\n");
                    i--;
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    num[i] = input;
                }
            }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A side-note: *Always* check the return value from `scanf`. If it's not *exactly* `1` here (indicating it successfully parsed one placeholder value), then you didn't get a new number.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: If I was writing the code, I'd have a variable `int found = false;`, and the only thing the `j` loop would do is set `found = true` if a match is found in the array. After the `j` loop finishes, you can decide what to do, based on the final value of `found`.

Comment: ...because you set `num[i] = input;` *inside* the checking loop, which won't run for the first element.

Comment: If you input directly into the array, then decrementing the outer loop counter should suffice. `scanf("%d", &num[i]);` and then `if(num[j] == num[i])`

Comment: @user3386109: No need here, since the behavior when it's not found is to back up `i` and read a new value for `num[i]`; unconditionally replacing the value of `num[i]` every time until the check loop doesn't cause it to back up works great, and avoids the need for a flag variable (and avoids the need for `input` as well). Side-note: If you're going to use a flag variable and initialize with `false` and `true`, may as well make the type `bool` instead of `int`; `bool`, `true` and `false` all come from `stdbool.h`, so if you use one, use 'em all.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thrashing the loop variable inside the loop body is bad practice. One of the core unix commands had a bug that went undetected for decades because of that. And having the `j` loop do anything more than just detect the presence of the number in the array is a violation of the KISS principle. In fact, well designed code would move the `j` loop to a separate, general purpose, reusable, and easily tested function who's only purpose is to determine whether a number exists in an array. Similar to the `memchr` library function.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop has a problem; it assigns `num[i] = input;` each time it doesn't see a duplicate (which is fine, it doesn't change the value after all, and you `break;` when a duplicate is found), but that means it never assigns `num[0]` at all the first time around (the inner loop never runs at all, because the first time around, `i == 0`, so the first `j < i` test is false).

Essentially, you don't see the duplicate because you never assigned on the first loop and there's no duplicate to see. That said, the contents of `num[0]` ends up being indeterminate, so you're getting unspecified data (or maybe undefined behavior, never recall) when you read it for your duplicate tests on other loops (in practice, it likely has a garbage value in it that, should you enter it yourself, will be treated as a duplicate, but only on the second and subsequent inputs, since it won't be checked the first time).

You need to change your code to assign `num[i] = input;` even if the inner loop never runs, ideally just once. The simplest solution is:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        scanf("%d", &input);  // You should really be checking the return value here

        num[i] = input; // Unconditionally assign, then check
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            if(num[j] == input){
                printf("You have already entered this number!\n");
                i--;
                break;
            }
            // No else case; we don't need to assign it once per check loop
        }
    }
```

The unconditional assignment here is fine, because if you do detect a duplicate, you back up anyway and you'll reassign it on the next loop, ignoring the value you just wrote.

You could simplify further and just skip the `input` variable entirely, and `scanf` directly into `num[i]` if you prefer (I minimized code changes to narrow the scope of the necessary fix), replacing two lines above with just `scanf("%d", &num[i]);`.